# Using Google Plus Sign In on Android to authenticate a user on the server side

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus-signin

I'm writing an app that requires a user sign in with Google on Android and then proceeds to get data from the server (a Google App Engine instance, in this case). How could I go about making sure that the user is actually logged in instead of just calling with a user ID? Is there a way for google to check a secure token they provide on Android for authenticity? Or is there another non-google related way to do this?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this is actually a very simple task. You ask Google Play Services for its OAuth Token and send that. Then the server asks Google about that token and Google will give it all of the information in the scope at once using one of their multiple limitless OAuth APIs.